# Extending the Domain of an Injective Set Map

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have sets $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ and a set $Y$, and we know that $|X_1|,|X_2| \leq |Y|$. Given an injective function $f : X_1 \to Y$, do we know for sure that there exists an extension $\tilde{f} : X_2 \to Y$ which is still injective? I feel like this should obvious, but I'm having trouble explicitly constructing such an extension. If we assume the axiom of choice, I bet we could build up from $f$ to $g$ by transfinite induction, but is there an easier and more elementary proof for this (maybe even one that doesn't assume choice)?

Comment: If $|X_1| = |Y|$, $f$ could be bijective between $X_1$ and $Y$, hence no extension with codomain $Y$ would ever hope to be injective?

Comment: You can extend it if and only if $|X_2\setminus X_1|\leq |Y\setminus f(X_1)|$. The assumptions you have do not ensure that.

Comment: For a concrete counterexample, take $X_1=(0,\infty)$, $X_2=[0,\infty)$, $Y=\Bbb R$, and $f(x)=\log x$.